# Do the elements of sample space constitute disjoint events?

Tags: probability-theory

Let, we be given a sample space $\Omega=\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$. Now, from the axioms of probability we know $P(\Omega)=1$. Also, from the definition of union of sets, we know, $\Omega=\{x_1\}\cup\{x_1\}\cup\{x_1\}$. Thus, $P(\Omega) = P(\{x_1\}\cup\{x_1\}\cup\{x_1\})=1$. Now, my question is, does this imply $$P(\{x_1\})+P(\{x_2\})+P(\{x_3\})=1?$$

Also, if yes, does this extend to sample spaces with countably infinite number of elements?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what the event space of your probability space is. If your event space is just $\{\{\}, \{x_1\}, \{x_2, x_3\}, \{x_1, x_2, x_3\}\}$ then it does not even make sense to talk about $P(\{x_2\})$ and $P(\{x_3\})$ since the probability measure is a function from your event space (usually denoted $\mathcal{F}$) to $[0,1]$. Now if your event space consists of all subsets of $\Omega$ then you are correct. This is because one of the axioms of a probability space is that the probability measure is countably additive. This means that if you have a countable collection of pairwise disjoint events: $\{A_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty }\subseteq {\mathcal {F}} $, then $P(\bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty }A_{i})=\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }P(A_{i})$.

Comment: Should that be $\{x_2,x_3\}$ instead of $\{x_1,x_2\}$?  Right now that isn't a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Yes that is a typo. Thanks for catching it!